# jQuery: Get iFrame Object from within an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iFrame (without id and name)

```
<iframe src="abc.jsp" scrolling="no" height="100" width="100%"></iframe>
```

I need to get the iFrame `Object` from within an iFrame to apply css. If there is a name, I could do `window.name`, but, there is no `Id` and `name`. So, is there a way to get iFrame object?

Comment: `$('iframe').content()` can help you to selest iframe object's or eleements.

Comment: the main page is `index.jsp` so, iFrame is in `index.jsp` and I'm in abc.jsp (iFrame)
So, `onLoaad()` of abc.jsp I need to apply some css in iFrame

Comment: Try using `parent`. It may cause a *CORS* exception as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.contents()` to change css in iframe
read http://api.jquery.com/contents/  example.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>contents demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="//api.jquery.com/" width="80%" height="600" ></iframe>

<script>
$( "iframe" ).contents().find( "a" ).css( "background-color", "#BADA55" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have an iFrame (without id and name)

Comment: change selector. it's easy!change selector like `$('iframe')` or if you have iframe's , you can change selector by eq like `$('iframe').eq(0)` or eq(n+1...)

Comment: I'm within the iFrame not in a parent window that opens the iFrame

Comment: I think This is not possible in `DOM`, And my answer is for just one parent and one child iframe in a document!